# Extend WooCommerce Product Filters plugin shortocodes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, shortcode

I am using Woocommerce with WOOF plugin (woocommerce filter). In particular, this plugin can display a filter that will only search in a specific product category using for example `[woof taxonomies=product_cat:23]` shortcode and display the results using the `[woof_products taxonomies=product_cat:23]` shortcode, where **`23`** is the category id of goods.

However, it is not always possible to specify a category in the shortcode itself, and I would like to implement functionality that allows you to use a shortcode like `[woof taxonomies=product_cat:auto]`, which will automatically determine the current category using a specific function, for example, this (the function is tested and works):

```
function show_product_category_id() {
    $cat = get_queried_object();
    $catID = $cat->term_id;
    if (empty($catID)) {
        //
        if (strpos($_GET['really_curr_tax'], 'product_cat')) {
            $catID=str_replace('-product_cat', '', $_GET['really_curr_tax']);
        }
        else {}
    }
    else {}
    echo $catID;
}
```

I can, of course, create a shortcode for this function, and add it to the theme's `functions.php`:

```php
add_shortcode( 'show_product_category_id', 'show_product_category_id' );
```

and it will work. But I can't use a construction like:

```php
[woof taxonomies=product_cat:[show_product_category_id]]
```

since nested shortcodes in Wordpress won't work. Therefore, apparently, I need to add to woocommerce the ability to specify not only product_cat:35, but also product_cat:auto.

How can i realize it? Or, is there also a way to use nested shortcodes in wordpress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course that you can't nest shortcodes one in another, but what you can do is embed a shortcode in a another shortcode as follows:

```
function woof_current_product_category_id() {
    $term    = get_queried_object();
    $term_id = 0; // Initializing

    if ( isset($_GET['really_curr_tax']) && false !== strpos( $_GET['really_curr_tax'], 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $term_id = (int) str_replace('-product_cat', '', $_GET['really_curr_tax']);
    } elseif ( is_a($term, 'WP_Term') ) {
        $term_id = (int) $term->term_id;
    }
    return do_shortcode("[woof taxonomies=product_cat:$term_id]"); // Always use return for a shortcode
}
add_shortcode( 'show_product_category_id', 'woof_current_product_category_id' );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

So the usage will simply be: `[show_product_category_id]`

Comment: This is what i need, sure. I have also made [show_result_product_category_id] shortcode for results (instead of [woof_products]). Thanks for the solution